# Web Reference in Visual Studio does not exsist...so cannot update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-reference

Basically, I have a web Service which I developed. I then went down to the installation site to install the web Service and a handheld app which uses it.

Problem is, I came back off site, and now need to change some things with the handheld app and web Service, and send it to them (site is hundreds of miles away).

I can change the web service fine, but how can I change the web reference to that web service, on the handheld app? its pointing to a location that does not exists as there is no remote access to their servers.

How can I trick Visual Studio into updating the web reference to get my LOCAL objects, but compiling to keep the web reference that only exists on THEIR local servers?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the url that the webreference is using by setting it to dynamic. It will add the url to the config.

Also see: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx